# Extract python wheels from pip wheel cache?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

It appears that pip now does automated caching of wheels:

http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#wheel-cache

I'm trying to collect wheels to create an installer for a custom learning setup (ipython3 notebook, etc), however, it appears that the cache uses a unreadable cache scheme.

Is there an easy way that the pip wheel cache can be dumped to the wheel files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`--download` (or `-d`) option](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-d):

```
$ pip install package --download /tmp
```

Above command will download the wheel into `/tmp` directory (uses cache if the wheel is already downloaded)